# Почему мой примитив (int) равен нулю?

Tags: java

Класс Army:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Army extends Frame {

private JLabel swords;
private JButton addSW;

private JLabel eswords;
private JButton addES;

private JButton battle;

private int army;
private int earmy;


Swords sw = new Swords();
Player play = new Player();
Enemy enem = new Enemy();




public Army()
{
    super();

    swords = new JLabel("Swords: " + play.getSwords());
    addSW = new JButton("Swords");
    battle = new JButton("Battle");

    JToolBar tq = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);

    tq.add(swords);
    tq.add(addSW);
    tq.add(battle);

    tq.setFloatable(false);

    add(tq, BorderLayout.WEST);

   // ---------------------------

    eswords = new JLabel("Swords: " + enem.getSwords());
    addES = new JButton("Choice");

    JToolBar tz = new JToolBar(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);

    tz.add(eswords);
    tz.add(addES);

    tz.setFloatable(false);

    add(tz, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //---------------------------

    addSW.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            play.setSwords(play.getSwords()+1);
            updateCountSW();

        }
    });


    addES.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            enem.Rnd();
            updateCountESW();
        }
    });

    battle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Bitva();
            updateCountESW();
            updateCountSW();
        }
    });

    army = play.getSwords()*sw.getPower();
    earmy = enem.getSwords()*sw.getPower();



}

private void updateCountSW()
{
    swords.setText("Swords: " + play.getSwords());


}

private void updateCountESW()
{
    eswords.setText("Swords: " + enem.getSwords());
}

private void Bitva()
{
    if(army>earmy)
    {
        play.setSwords(play.getSwords() - enem.getSwords());
    }

}


}
```

Класс Enemy:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Enemy {

private int swords;
Random rnd = new Random();

public int getSwords() {
    return swords;
}

public void setSwords(int swords) {
    this.swords = swords;
}

public void Rnd()
{
    swords = (rnd.nextInt(50));

}

}
```

Класс Player:

```
public class Player {

private int swords;

public int getSwords() {
    return swords;
}

public void setSwords(int swords) {
    this.swords = swords;
}
}
```

Класс Swords:

```
public class Swords {

private int power = 15;

public int getPower() {
    return power;
}

public void setPower(int power) {
    this.power = power;
}
}
```

---

Мой метод `Bitva` ничего не делает, протестировав, я понял, что в `army = play.getSwords()` - равен нулю...
Ребят, я совсем запутался в этом примитиве. Ответ вроде очевиден, но я просто не могу разобрать, почему `play.getSwords()` равен нулю. Я попробовал использовать разные костыли, но НИЧЕГО не получается. Укажите правильный путь, что не так. Чего я не понимаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примитив `int` при отсутствии явной инициализации инициализируется нулём.

Вы `int` переменную не инициализировали, засим она равна нулю.

Comment: Хорошо, я проблему понял.
Но как инициализировать правильно? Я уже сто и один способ попробовал, не идет мне на ум верное решение.

Comment: @OgneFF, ну так у вас же есть для этого вами же написанный сеттер... Просто вызовете его после создания экземпляра класса.

Comment: не разобрался. Без явного примера, инициализация моего решения будет равна нулю)). 
Сеттер класса Player надо вызвать в классе Army после создания экземпляра класса? У меня стало еще больше вопросов.
 play.setSwords(army) - только это на ум приходит, и никак не помогает

Comment: @OgneFF, `army` у вас тоже неинициализирована и потому равна нулю. Вам надо ей присвоить число. Например так : `army=5;` `play.setSwords(army);`

Answer (score 1):

С `getSwords` у вас все хорошо, он работает. Внутри `Bitva()` не вызывается `play.setSwords`, т.к. значения полей `Army.army` и `Army.earmy` у вас вычисляются только один раз в конце конструктора и равны нулю. Поэтому ветвь условного оператора в `Bitva()` не выполняется никогда.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вам уже ответили, но не совсем корректно. Инициализируются сами только поля классов. Все примитивы нулями, а все ссылочные классы нулом(`null`). Тут кстати могут быть разные странные поведения при наследовании и последовательности инициализации полей класса.

Если же вы попробуете использовать не ициализированную переменную объявленную в методе, то компилятор вам на это ругнется(`variable *variable_name* might not have been initialized`) и не будет ничего компилировать.